# es6 imports: name imported variables

Tags: ecmascript-6, es6-modules

I have a huge list of permissions, and I'm only interested in importing three of them. I'm also interested in grouping them in an object and assigning a variable to that object.

Can I do any better than the following?

```
import {
  firstPermission,
  secondPermission,
  thirdPermission,
} from '@constants/permissions';

const relevantPermissions = { firstPermission, secondPermission, thirdPermission };
```

I was inclined to try using the `as` keyword in the `import` step, but I couldn't get any such thing to work.

(This feels like an ignorant question; please forgive.)

Comment: Why do you care about only those three being on the object? If it doesn't matter, just use a namespace import - it's not less efficient.

Comment: @Bergi Thanks for asking. The huge list of permissions is like 150-200 sets. I'm only interested in checking the relevance of these three. I suppose I could `import * as allPermissions from '@constants/permissions'`, but I suspect this would be confusing to other developers I'm working with. Also, I'd have to write out a list of the relevant permissions I'm interested in anyway, so that I could access `allPermissions[firstPermission]`, `allPermissions[ secondPermission]`, and so on. Thoughts?

Comment: I wouldn't think it's confusing, but you'd have to ask your fellow developers. Sure, if you need this collection (list) of relevant permissions, then your approach is fine, as well as @estus' answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`as` keyword is intended to import named exports under different names, not group them.

The code listed in the question is the way this should be done. If `relevantPermissions` is supposed to be used in multiple places, it's beneficial to re-export them:

```
export {
  firstPermission,
  secondPermission,
  thirdPermission,
} from '@constants/permissions';

...

import * as relevantPermissions from './relevant-permissions';
```

This way named imports have a chance to be tree-shaken if some of them remain unused, also may get other benefits of ES modules such as improved code completion in IDEs.